# Некорректно работает второй цикл

Tags: c++

Будьте любезны, наведите на путь истинный. Второй цикл while некорректно работает, в чем причина?

```
while (i <= a)  
{  
    i++;  
}
```

---

```
while (j <= b)  
{  
    j+=i;                               // второй цикл...
}
```

---

Например, переменной `а` равняется число 2, а переменной `в` равняется 3. В первом цикле происходит преобразование числа 2 в : 1+1, во втором цикле выражение 1+1 повторяется 3 раза. Другими словами, замена умножения делением. Проблема в том что, первый цикл отрабатывает на ура, второй цикл не выполняется вовсе.

Comment: А можно больше информации? Непонятно, что должно быть и какая ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

1) отформатируйте код, для этого есть специальная кнопка

2) " не корректно" - это как?

3) вопрос немного не по теме, но просто бросается в глаза. Зачем вам вот эта конструкция:

```
while (i <= a)
{
    i++;
}
```

не проще ли сразу написать **i = a + 1;**?

**Обновление**

> эта конструкция производит преобразование допустим числа 5 в 1+1+1+1+1

тут не будет никакого "преобразования". в памяти вы получите то же самое число 5, а не 1+1+..., поэтому весь ваш цикл будет иметь тот же эффект, что и обычное присваивание, только выполнится в несколько раз медленнее

**Обновление**

[[@АльфаЧ](/users/26456/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%87)](/users/26456/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%87) вашу логику очень трудно назвать логичной. Если вы хотите заменить умножение сложением, зачем вам прибавлять единицы?

Эта простая идея замены умножения на сложение реализуется элементарно (в первом приближении):

```
int multiply(int first, int second) 
{
    int res = 0;
    while(second-- > 0)
        res += first;

    return res;
}
```

Правда это дрянная реализация Она неверно обрабатывает отрицательные множители и заглохнет на больших значениях в силу переполнения, но от этих недостатков можно исцелиться, добавив чуть больше кода. Но это уже другая история

Comment: Попробую описать в точности, чего я желал, написанием сея кода. Я написал, это громко сказано, попытался написать программу, позволявшую бы мне произвести умножение, заменив его сложением через единицу. первый цикл while как я считаю , произвел, таковой эффект с первым множителем. Затем при помощи второго цикла я попытался повторить произведенный эффект в колличестве нужном, отображающим второй множитель. Как то так.

Comment: если это так, то у вас и первый цикл работает неверно - вы не выполняете в нем никакого умножения, а несколько раз прибавляете к переменной единицу, что не является аналогом умножения. 

Если же вы хотите умножение **a** на **b** заменить сложением, то, как подсказывает арифметика второго класса, вам нужно сложить число **а** само с собой в количестве **b** штук

Comment: Да, вот именно этой арифметикой я и руководствовался.Как я считаю, что вышенаписанными циклами выполняю это десйтвие то бишь:
(1+1)//первый цикл
(1+1 + 1+1 1+1)//второй цикл
То есть 2*3. Но черт ногу сломит, в  такой казалось бы пустяковой задаче.

Answer (score 0):

Арифметика второго класса (не первого, которой Вы руководствуетесь) говорит, что надо сделать

```
int n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    n+=a;
```

Нет, складывать единички, конечно, можно. Только зачем?
Не, ну можно и так написать...

```
int n = 0;
while (++n!=a*b);
```

Дело Ваше...